# Scrapy response.css has empty list

Tags: css, scrapy

Need the get the Product name and Price from this page
https://www.lazada.com.my/shop-smart-tvs/

Started with

> > scrapy shell "https://www.lazada.com.my/shop-smart-tvs/"

The output I got was this.
response   <200 https://www.lazada.com.my/shop-smart-tvs/>

I also used proxy and user-agents, to make sure there wasn't any blocks.

But when I used

> > > response.css(".c13VH6 , .c16H9d a").css('::text').extract()
> > >       and 
> > >       response.css(".c16H9d a::attr(title)").extract()

I get blank lists []
Tried the same approach with another site, this works.

P.S. I used a Chrome CSS selector widget to get the CSS selectors.

Please tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: SO is not a place where you just drop in your request and someone else solves it. Please show us you code, highlight where you got stuck and which parts causes problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is probably loaded dynamically, so you would have to render the page with something like Splash or Selenium to make your CSS expression work.

When you go to the page source you can see the product data is present in a big json-file, so I would just load the json as a python dictionary, and get the data you want from there:

```
import scrapy
import json


class LazadaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lazada'
    allowed_domains = ['lazada.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.lazada.com.my/shop-smart-tvs/']

    def parse(self, response):
        script = response.xpath(
            "//script[starts-with(text(), 'window.pageData')]/text()"
        ).extract_first()
        first = script.index('{')
        last = len(script)
        products = json.loads(script[first:last])
        items = products['mods']['listItems']
        for item in items:
            name = item['name']
            price = item['price']
            yield {'name': name,
                   'price': price}
```